# Getting a one to one morphism $p : G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am studying representation theory, and I would like to find an algorithm that finds, given a finite group $G$, a one to one morphism $p : G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (the integer $n$ is also found by the algorithm). I don't necessarily want this algorithm to be efficient. First is it possible to make such an algorithm ?

Now I am wondering how to begin with. I thought about finding the character table of the group first (I know this not an easy task) and find its irreductible representations, but then from here I don't see how I can find a solution to my problem. 
If I have all the irreductible representations of my group I don't see how I can get $p$. I mean the characters only give information about the sum on the digonal of $p(g)$, but how to get from this information the other entries in the matrices ?

Thank you !

Comment: "given a group $G$" is important. i removed the parentheses

Comment: Take a look at Theorem 2.12 of "Introduction to Representation Theory" by Etingof (for finite groups only). Since the field is $\mathbb{C}$, $A=\mathbb{C}[G]$ is semisimple, and therefore there is an isomorphism of algebras $A\cong \oplus_i End(V_i)$, where $V_i$ are the irreducible representations of $G$.

Comment: @mathworker21 when I say given a group $G$ it means any type of group theoric description of $G$ (for example Cayley table)

Comment: If $G$ is finite you can just use $n=\#G$ with the regular representation.  For infinite $G$ we may not have finite dimensional faithful representation.

Comment: @user10354138 Right, actually I am only interested when $\mid G \mid < \infty$. But is there a procedure to find the matrices of the regular representation ?

Comment: @Javi Thank you ! But I still need to find $End(V_i)$ no ?

Comment: Matrices of the regular representations are easily extracted from the Caley table.
Try at hand with the symmetric group of order 6.

Answer (score 3):

Every finite group embeds into a permutation group; this is [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley's_theorem). The proof of the theorem is essentially constructive, with $G$ embedding into $S_{|G|}$. That is, there is an algorithm with input a Cayley table* of a finite group $G$ and output a permutation group $\operatorname{Perm}(G)$ isomorphic to $G$. You can then easily embed $\operatorname{Perm}(G)$ into $\operatorname{GL}_{|G|}(\mathbb{C})$ using [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix), and again this can be made algorithmic.

*The input form can vary, but the OP explicitly mentions Cayley tables in the comments.

Comment: Thankfully, the OP also explicitly mentioned that the algorithm didn't need to be efficient ! (well this one is very quick to find the morphism, but the $n$ it produces is most often far from optimal)

Comment: The constructive proof of Cayley's Theorem is essentially the content of my answer, except that instead of embedding in $S_{|G|}$, I've further mapped $S_{|G|}$ into $SO(|G|)$ so that you get an actual faithful representation of $G$ in the orthogonal group.

Answer (score 1):

Take a group, with elements $g_1, \ldots, g_n$.

Associate to $g_1$ the vector $e_1 \in \Bbb R^n$.

Now for element $g_1$, compute the $n$ items
$$
g_1 \cdot g_1, g_1 \cdot g_2, \ldots, g_1 \cdot g_n.
$$
These will be the elements of $G$, in some new order, such as 
$$
g_7, g_2, \ldots, g_3.
$$
Write down the corresponding vectors as the columns of a matrix 
$$
M_1 = \pmatrix{ e_7, e_2, \ldots, e_3}
$$
Do the same for $g_2$ to produce $M_2$, and so on.

The map $g_1 \mapsto M_1, g_2 \mapsto M_2, \ldots$ will be a injective homomorphism of groups.

(Unless I've messed up and forgotten a transpose somewhere...)

You can test this out pretty quickly by trying it for $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$, or even $S_3$.